# unable to ping google or smb personal server

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ping, smb

I am unable to ping google or my personal server. I suspect this is also why I have issues connecting to my server using smb. Here is the output:

```
[~]$ ping http://google.com   
ping: cannot resolve http://google.com: Unknown host
```

I'm not really even sure where to start with this - any help is appreciated.

screenshot here: http://kyleouellette.com/smb-issues/screenshot.png

Comment: please post the output from pinging your smb server also.

Comment: Are you on the same LAN as the smb server?

Comment: cpast no it's a vps

Comment: Did SMB used to work, or did it never work? Does it work on other computers?

Comment: cpast yea it works when I'm at work so I think maybe it has something to do with either this machine or my network here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the `http://` in there. Just do `ping google.com`.

The `http://` just identifies a protocol: essentially, how your computer should talk to the one at `google.com`. Specifically, it says "I want to see a website" (pretty much). But `ping` just needs to know what computer to try to talk to in the first place. That's the `google.com` bit - it gets translated into an IP address, and `ping` sends packets to that IP.

Comment: Thanks cpast - looks like that solved the ping issue. I'm able to ping both my server as well as google now. Any idea why I wouldn't be able to connect via smb to my personal server?